# Manually create SOAP Messages?

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl, apache-commons-exec

My goal is to set up a generic web service. By "generic" in this context I mean that, one should be able to run an arbitrary sequence of tools on the input (let's say a file). 
These tools are compiled programms installed on the server.

My idea was to specify each tool in a central `WSDL` File. This `WSDL` File is parsed and for each tool, included in the `WSDL` file, a separate `Service Class` is created, which executes the respective tool via apache commons exec.

Is it then possible to manually create a `SOAP Message` in which the sequence of tools, one wants to perform on the input, is specified ? This `SOAP Message` should then be parsed and the respective `Service Classes` should be started.

I have to say I'm completely new to `Web Service` programming and I'm gratefuly for any advice. The above is just an idea and I'm open for any better advice ;)

greetings,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create, modify `SOAP` messages manually (programmatically) by implementing `SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` interface. Then you need to override this method:

```
public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
   //do anything you like with a message    
}
```

You get the `SOAP` message from `SOAPMessageContext` object passed into this method:

```
SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
```

From your message you can get `SOAP Body`, `SOAP Envelope`, `SOAP Header`. You can add as many element as you like by doing this. But do not forget that every element you add manually must match your `XSD` of your `WSDL` file.

To declare this handler into `JAX-WS` context you can `Spring` configuration as follows:

```
  <jaxws:endpoint id="HandlerExample"
                  implementor="your.service.ImplemetationClass"
                  address="http://localhost:8080/Example/services/Example">
    <jaxws:handlers>
       <bean class="your.Handler" />
    </jaxws:handlers>
  </jaws:endpoint>
```

More information about how to configure `JAX-WS` endpoint you can find [here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-ws-configuration.html). Also information about handlers you can find [here](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/jax-ws-soap-handler-in-server-side/).

Hope this helps for a start.